# how to save the operations(add/update) done by authenticated user into a log file

Tags: users

I need to write the sql operations(update/add) performed by an authenticated user of my drupal site into a log file/database table. I simply need the query executed, uid, timestamp of that operation done.

For example if a user named "XYZ" logged into my site and updated his firstname at 12/12/12 12:12:12. while he updated the query run in the backend would be "UPDATE  `db_name`.`table_name` SET  `firstname` =  'ABC' WHERE  `table_name`.`firstname` =XYZ;"

I need to store it into my database custom table which has the three fields `uid`, `sql`, `timestamp`

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using ? I dont think there are any hooks which will let you modify a DB Query in D6, so probably you have to modify core Drupal file for this.

Comment: Can you post some example code on how to do this?